# Why don't any of these methods work for installing .Net Core SDK & runtime on 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)?

Tags: development, microsoft, sdk, dotnet

I went to the following [official Microsoft link to install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2204) .NET Core 6.x (SDK & runtime) and they would not work.

Basically, it tells you to :

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Then to install SDK you are supposed to run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Then to install runtime it says to run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
```

But when I ran all of that, I got a weird thing where the runtime was "half installed".

I could run `$ dotnet --list-sdks` and it wouldn't report any SDK.

Also, I couldn't run the simple command `$ dotnet --version`  It would state that no SDKs were installed and the command couldn't run.  Very confusing.

I also got an error like:

> Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-6.0

Microsoft says to choose the following link to resolve that: [APT troubleshooting section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#apt-troubleshooting).

**Tried Snap**
I also tried installing the snap.  Again, dotnet runtime still didn't work properly.
I tried various removing and rebooting and many options but could never get the SDK installed properly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I make it run with the APT package solution, in fact
there is a conflict between Ubuntu packages (Jammy feed) and Microsoft Package (PMC), more info here:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699

The solution with the following steps works for me:
`Use .NET 6 Package via PMC`

1. Remove all .NET packages

```
sudo apt remove 'dotnet*'
sudo apt remove 'aspnetcore*'
```

2. Create the file:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences.d/dotnet.pref
```

with content:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "packages.microsoft.com"
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

3. Install .NET SDK 6.0

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

And I got the last version of the SDK:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.400 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm on Ubuntu 22.04! I used specific version to install: `sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0=6.0.301`

Answer (score 2):

The following simple command has fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```