# The command could not be loaded, possibly because: * You intended to execute a .NET application:

Tags: command-line, 22.04, dotnet

I am using dotnet6 in my ubuntu 22.04 version. Right now when I run dotnet --version, I am getting the below error.

```
jyothish@jyothish-Lenovo-G570:~$ dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
jyothish@jyothish-Lenovo-G570:~$
```

At the same time when I run dotnet --help and dotnet --list-runtimes, I am getting output.

```
jyothish@jyothish-Lenovo-G570:~$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
jyothish@jyothish-Lenovo-G570:~$ dotnet --help

Usage: dotnet [host-options] [path-to-application]

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.

host-options:
  --additionalprobingpath <path>  Path containing probing policy and assemblies to probe for.
  --depsfile <path>               Path to <application>.deps.json file.
  --runtimeconfig <path>          Path to <application>.runtimeconfig.json file.
  --fx-version <version>          Version of the installed Shared Framework to use to run the application.
  --roll-forward <value>          Roll forward to framework version (LatestPatch, Minor, LatestMinor, Major, LatestMajor, Disable)
  --additional-deps <path>        Path to additional deps.json file.
  --list-runtimes                 Display the installed runtimes
  --list-sdks                     Display the installed SDKs

Common Options:
  -h|--help                       Displays this help.
  --info                          Display .NET information.
jyothish@jyothish-Lenovo-G570:~
```

How can I correct this and resume using dotnet6 in ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't any of these methods work for installing .Net Core SDK & runtime on 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422947/why-dont-any-of-these-methods-work-for-installing-net-core-sdk-runtime-on-22)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen this helped. Thanks. But I had another problem. I had a broken installation of dotnet6 I think. When I removed that, the dotnet command is now executing the new files which is downloaded from windows. Its working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you don't have an SDK installed. I'm guessing you have just the runtime. Do:

```
sudo apt install dotnet6
```

If it tells you you have errors, do

```
sudo apt -f install
```

If that doesn't work, uninstall ALL dotnet packages and reinstall dotnet6